# programmatically reinitialize a controller within a container view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a toolbar with a segmented control underneath a navbar that controls which of 3 stacked container views (each with their own view controller) is not hidden (i.e if 1 is selected in the segmented control, container views 2 and 3 are .hidden). I have a button in view 1, and when that button is pressed I essentially want it to reinitialize view 3 and go thru its viewDidLoad. Is something like this possible without the app crashing? Or is there a different way I have to go about this problem?

The super simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve: View 1 has a join/leave button. View 3 is only "available" (there is some more complex stuff going in the initialization) if the user is joined. The problem is that since both views are within View Containers within a "master" view, the one that holds the toolbar with the segmented control, they are all initialized at the same time, so View 3 is initialized before any join/leave action can be taken in View 1. And when a join/leave action is taken in View 1, I want to reinitialize View 3 appropriately

Comment: Use a delegation pattern between view 1 and your "master" so that the view can tell the master that the. Hutton was pushed. In the delegate method the master can do what is required (Ie, create a new instance of view3)

Comment: Would help if you showed the crashing code and the crash log.